# Rails input_html being reapplied

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails 3.2 - I sometimes use `:input_html` on forms.

For example:

```
<%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', :input_html => {:checked => true} %>
```

If the user unchecked the box and submits the form and there are some validation errors, the check box gets checked again.

Is there a way to leave it unchecked?

Thanks for your help!

UDPATE1

I changed the code to this:

```
    <% if params.has_key?(:assign_client) %>
        <%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?' %>
    <% else %>
        <%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', :input_html => {:checked => true} %>
    <% end %>
```

But, that didn't work.

Comment: In the controller action, you could set the value of `assign_client` to `false` or `0` before rendering the page again to display error messages. Then remove the `input_html` helper attribute tag from your line of code.

Comment: @Alexander That would uncheck the checkbox even if the user has checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `params` hash will contain the `assign_client` key if the checkbox was checked by the user. So, you could do something like this:

```
<%= f.input :assign_client, :label => 'Charge Client?', :input_html => { :checked => params.has_key?(:assign_client) } %>
```

Comment: @Reddirt It should be the other way around. When the `params` has the key `assign_client` than it should be checked. That's what my example does, did you try that?